# QuickBlox retrieving chats dialogs Android

Tags: android, quickblox

i'm building an android chat app with quickblox ..
and when i want to retrieve the chats dialogs list and the users list it's not appeared on my screen.. 
i had searched for this problem and i found that i had to enable the user list retrieving.. 
so i did that but nothing changed ...
Here's my ChatDialogsList code:

```
package shashoug.com.zoolisd;

    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.quickblox.auth.QBAuth;
    import com.quickblox.auth.session.BaseService;
    import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSession;
    import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSettings;
    import com.quickblox.chat.QBChatService;
    import com.quickblox.chat.QBRestChatService;
    import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog;
    import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback;
    import com.quickblox.core.exception.BaseServiceException;
    import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;
    import com.quickblox.core.request.QBRequestGetBuilder;
    import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import shashoug.com.zoolisd.Adapter.ChatDialogAdapter;

    public class ChatDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView chatListDialogs;
    private FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_dialog);

        floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        chatListDialogs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstChatsDialog);
        createSessionForChat();
        loadAllChat();
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatDialogActivity.this,ListUsersActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    private void loadAllChat() {
        QBRequestGetBuilder requestBuilder = new QBRequestGetBuilder();
        requestBuilder.setLimit(100);
        QBRestChatService.getChatDialogs(null,requestBuilder).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBChatDialog>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBChatDialog> qbChatDialogs, Bundle bundle) {
                ChatDialogAdapter adapter = new ChatDialogAdapter(getBaseContext(),qbChatDialogs);
                chatListDialogs.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
              Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    private void createSessionForChat() {
        final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChatDialogActivity.this);
        mDialog.setTitle("Retreiveing The Dialogs");
        mDialog.setMessage("Please Wait While We Collecting your Chats Info.");
        mDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        mDialog.show();
        String name,password;
        name = getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
        password = getIntent().getStringExtra("password");
         final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser(name,password);
        QBAuth.createSession(qbUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {
                mDialog.dismiss();
                qbUser.setId(qbSession.getUserId());
                try {
                    qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
                } catch (BaseServiceException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                QBChatService.getInstance().login(qbUser, new QBEntityCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Object o, Bundle bundle) {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                     Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                Log.e("ERROR",e.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here's my ChatsDialogAdapter code:

package shashoug.com.zoolisd.Adapter;

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.TextDrawable;
    import com.amulyakhare.textdrawable.util.ColorGenerator;
    import com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import shashoug.com.zoolisd.R;

    public class ChatDialogAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<QBChatDialog> qbChatDialogs;

    public ChatDialogAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<QBChatDialog> qbChatDialogs) {
        this.context = context;
        this.qbChatDialogs = qbChatDialogs;
    }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
        return qbChatDialogs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return qbChatDialogs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view ==null)
        {
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_chat_dialog,null);
            TextView txtTitle;
            TextView txtMessage;
            ImageView imageView;
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_chat_dialog_title);
            txtMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_chat_dialog_message);
            imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_chat_dialog);
            txtMessage.setText(qbChatDialogs.get(position).getLastMessage());
            txtTitle.setText(qbChatDialogs.get(position).getName());
            ColorGenerator generator = ColorGenerator.MATERIAL;
            int randomColor = generator.getRandomColor();
            TextDrawable.IBuilder builder = TextDrawable.builder().beginConfig()
                    .withBorder(4)
                    .endConfig()
                    .round();
            TextDrawable drawable = builder.build(txtTitle.getText().toString().substring(0,1).toUpperCase(),randomColor);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);





        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use my solution below? what was result?

Answer (score 0):

In your case you call asynchronous method createSessionForChat() and at once call method loadAllChat() in result you start loading dialogs at the same time with session creation. You need call method loadAllChat() after success creating QB session.